# kCGBlendModeClear Erases but then line reappears

Tags: ios, objective-c, paint, drawrect

I am currently using drawRect method to allow the user to paint with their finger. I use kCGBlendModeClear to clear part of the painting. However, when I begin to paint again using kCGBlendModeNormal if I move my finger over the area that was once erased, it paints it into view. Very strange.

I have looked all over and tried alot of different suggestions but I can't get anything to work. Anyone able to help?

In Touches Moved:

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self];

CGFloat dx = point.x - currentPoint.x;
CGFloat dy = point.y - currentPoint.y;

if ((dx * dx + dy * dy) < kPointMinDistanceSquared) {
    return;
}


previousPoint2 = previousPoint1;
previousPoint1 = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

CGPoint mid1 = midPoint(previousPoint1, previousPoint2);
CGPoint mid2 = midPoint(currentPoint, previousPoint1);
CGMutablePathRef subpath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(subpath, NULL, mid1.x, mid1.y);
CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(subpath, NULL, previousPoint1.x, previousPoint1.y, mid2.x, mid2.y);
CGRect bounds = CGPathGetBoundingBox(subpath);

CGPathAddPath(path, NULL, subpath);
CGPathRelease(subpath);

CGRect drawBox = bounds;
drawBox.origin.x -= self.lineWidth * 2.0;
drawBox.origin.y -= self.lineWidth * 2.0;
drawBox.size.width += self.lineWidth * 4.0;
drawBox.size.height += self.lineWidth * 4.0;

[self setNeedsDisplayInRect:drawBox];
```

In drawRect:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextAddPath(context, path);
CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 10);

if (eraserSelected) {

     //////Erase/////// 
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 37.0);

}else {

    //////Paint///////
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetAlpha (context, 0.75);


}


CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

Comment: Are you storing the lines and drawing them each time or just rendering into a context each time the touch moves?

Comment: I am rendering them into context each time the touch moves.

Comment: By 'them', do you mean stored lines or just the new part between the last location and the new location of the touch? Show some code.

Comment: I have updated my question with code. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you only have one line. That single line is updated each time the touch point moves and you redraw the area just around the touch point. The area redrawn uses whatever the current 'tool' is (eraser or pen). As a result, the state of the eraser / pen when the user drew any line segment isn't saved.

To fix this you need to create a new line, at least each time the user changes the 'tool' (probably each time they end a touch session). That line should be saved with the 'tool' type that was active at the time and an order number (so you can draw them in order when you come to `drawRect`).

Comment: That's a great answer. Thanks! I will take that and fix the problem.